# What is the reason to put in the queue when the combined weight is less than the node weight?

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

As you see the code, first I heappush the edge vertex to the queue after checking if the edge vertex is not visited but it was wrong. 
To get the right answer, I had to heappush after checking the value if the combined values are less than the vertex weight. 
Why is that?

```
 for edge in current.edge_list:
            if edge.to_vertex.is_not_visited():
         ## I first appended the to_vertex to the queue, but it does not work
                total_weight = current_weight + edge.weight
                if total_weight < edge.to_vertex.key:
                    heapq.heappush(queue, edge.to_vertex)
                    edge.to_vertex.key = total_weight
                    edge.to_vertex.parent = current
                    current.visited = True
```

Comment: maybe it means that you found shorter route and it is good to check this route later.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, you initially had heappush in a place of the comment and the rest of the code (except heappush ofc) was exactly the same?

Comment: Does it even work now? You mark node as visited when you find any path that costs less then initial cost (I guess you set it as INF, so basically it happens every time you find any path), not necessarily the shortest one. You should mark a node only when you take it from the heap, thats when you can be sure that you've found the shortest path. Rest of the code is ok, the place of heappush shouldn't do any difference (except the memory used)

Comment: This code works strangely and pass some of the online judge. I just wanted to know of what I am not sure of. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have defined `__lt__` in your vertex class for use by heapq. Storing distance information as an attribute might destroy your min heap invariants whenever you change value of `key` attribute for a vertex. And in your code snippet I am not seeing anything which re-establishes the invariants.

**Explanation:** while `to_vertex` is in the same place as before in your min heap, you might have changed its key enough to be smaller than its parent or larger than any of its children. Only the former may happens when you put the check `total_weight < edge.to_vertex.key`.

**Advice:** use a min heap of tuples `(<key>, <vertex>)` instead.

The following might also help fix some other problems with your code:

1. When `heapq.heappop(queue)` returns `current`, you first have to check if it is already visited. If not, mark it visited, i.e. `current.visited = True`, and **then** iterate over the outgoing edges (i.e. `for edge in current.edge_list: ...`). We check if `current` was already visited because there might be multiple entries of this vertex in `queue`.
2. Whenever `total_weight < edge.to_vertex.key`, you must push `edge.to_vertex` into your min heap. This is because you just found a shorter way to reach this vertex through `current`. Of course, you already know this.
3. Consider the order of statements `heapq.heappush(queue, edge.to_vertex)` and `edge.to_vertex.key = total_weight` in your code. You are pushing the `to_vertex` into `queue` **before** updating its weight. This problem goes away if you use, as suggested above, a min heap of tuples.